# Remove runnable from handler

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-studio, timer

I have created a thread to be called after some time to update time using  `Handler` i want stop it when time finish by removing it from handler using `handler.removeCallbacks(runnable)` . So i use a boolean flag inside thread to stop it.

**Issue:** Time finish values of time starts going negative but thread is not getting stoped. i have seen in logs `handler.removeCallbacks(runnable)` is also getting called.

what i am missing here.

```
private Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        time.setText(
            String.format(
                "%d:%d",
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(AppController.RunningTime),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(AppController.RunningTime) -
                TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(AppController.RunningTime)
                )
            )
        );
        AppController.RunningTime = AppController.RunningTime - 10000;
        if (AppController.RunningTime <= 0) {
            // inform user about your time is finished.
            handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
            openTimeUpDailog(mContext);
        }
        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
};
runnable.run();
```

Comment: it is actually runable working as countdown timer.

Comment: Show the complete code

Comment: you should not start runnable via calling `run()`. Instead of that create `Thread`. `Thread th = new Thread(runnable);`, and when it is created, start the thread: `th.start();`.

Comment: Thanks @RafaelOsipov i will modify it according your approach.

Comment: @SohailZahid If you could fix your own issue, please don't update your question to give the answer. Answer your own question instead.

Comment: @NicolasFilotto so should i Answer my question now or leave it.And next be careful.

Comment: @SohailZahid no do it now, otherwise it is confusing we don't know if you have your answer or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update Found problem**

It stopped, but started counting again because **handler.postDelayed(this, 1000)** is still called.

This will fix the problem.

```
if (AppController.RunningTime <= 0) {
    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    openTimeUpDailog(mContext);
} else {
    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
}
```